# Multi List JS not responding

Tags: javascript, python, html, excel, csv

I have an excel sheet with multiple category lists. These lists are updated on daily basis. I have to display these lists as HTML and have to run a script so that the list acts as a shopping list with a add and subtract button with each item. The add and subtract button is adding and subtracting on the basis of a hidden multiplier with each item. Each list will have its individual sum after the quantity is multiplied by its respective price and give a list total at the end of the list. Similarly a grand total is generated at the end of the page.

To convert it I opted to write a Python script that converts the CSV data into the required HTML with all the functionalities. But the JS is giving problem and not providing the correct results.

Where is the mistake?

```
import csv

# Define the CSV file path 
csv_file = 'test.csv'

# Read data from the CSV file into a list of dictionaries
data = []
with open(csv_file, 'r', newline='') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(row)

# Initialize a dictionary to store shopping lists and their items
shopping_lists = {}

# Group items by shopping list
for row in data:
    list_name = row['List']
    item_name = row['Item']
    price = float(row['Price'])

    if list_name not in shopping_lists:
        shopping_lists[list_name] = {'items': [], 'total': 0.0}

    shopping_lists[list_name]['items'].append({'name': item_name, 'price': price})
    shopping_lists[list_name]['total'] += price

# Define the HTML template
html_template = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Shopping Lists</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .item {
            flex: 1;
        }

        .price {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

        button {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            background-color: #007bff;
            color: #fff;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .list-total {
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: right;
        }

        #total {
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-align: right;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping Lists</h1>
"""

# Generate HTML for each shopping list
for list_name, list_data in shopping_lists.items():
    list_html = f"""
    <div id="list-container-{list_name.replace(" ", "-")}">
        <h2>{list_name}</h2>
        <ul class="shopping-list">
    """

    for item in list_data['items']:
        item_html = f"""
            <li>
                <div class="item">{item['name']}</div>
                <div class="price">${item['price']}</div>
                <button class="add">+</button>
                <span class="quantity">0.00</span>
                <button class="subtract">-</button>
            </li>
        """
        list_html += item_html

    list_total_html = f"""
        </ul>
        <div class="list-total">
            <strong>List Total: $<span class="list-grand-total">0.00</span></strong>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const listContainer = document.querySelector('#list-container-{list_name.replace(" ", "-")}');
        const items = listContainer.querySelectorAll("li");
        const listTotalElement = listContainer.querySelector(".list-grand-total");

        items.forEach((item) => {{
            const addButton = item.querySelector(".add");
            const subtractButton = item.querySelector(".subtract");
            const quantityElement = item.querySelector(".quantity");
            const priceElement = item.querySelector(".price");

            let quantity = 0;

            addButton.addEventListener("click", () => {{
                quantity++;
                quantityElement.textContent = quantity.toFixed(2); // Display quantity with 2 decimal places
                updateTotal();
            }});

            subtractButton.addEventListener("click", () => {{
                if (quantity > 0) {{
                    quantity--;
                    quantityElement.textContent = quantity.toFixed(2); // Display quantity with 2 decimal places
                    updateTotal();
                }}
            }});

            function updateTotal() {{
                const price = parseFloat(priceElement.textContent.slice(1)); // Remove the "$" sign and parse as float
                const itemTotal = price * quantity;
                list_data.total += itemTotal; // Update list total
                listTotalElement.textContent = list_data.total.toFixed(2); // Display list total with 2 decimal places
                updateCombinedTotal();
            }}
        }});

        function updateCombinedTotal() {{
            const combinedTotalElement = document.getElementById("grand-total");
            let combinedTotal = 0;
            document.querySelectorAll('.list-grand-total').forEach((listTotal) => {{
                combinedTotal += parseFloat(listTotal.textContent);
            }});
            combinedTotalElement.textContent = combinedTotal.toFixed(2); // Display combined total with 2 decimal places
        }}
    </script>
    """

    html_template += list_html + list_total_html

# Add the combined total section to the HTML
html_template += """
    <div id="total">
        <strong>Combined Total: $<span id="grand-total">0.00</span></strong>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
"""

# Save the generated HTML to a file
output_file = 'output.html'
with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
    file.write(html_template)

print(f"HTML file '{output_file}' has been generated.")
```

I have tried the above code and the buttons are not adding or subtracting properly also the grand totals are not working perfectly

Comment: "Does not work" is not a problem. Give more details.

Comment: what other details are required Sir. I need that the buttons with each item should add and subtract. Should get a list sum and a page sum.